# How to display all the shipping details in system.log after clicking on Place Order Button

Tags: magento-1

I want to display all the shipping details on system.log when user clicks Place Order button. I used event handler to display Customer Id and Customer name, but I am unable to display other details like Product name, Order Id, Address, Price, Quantity etc. How can I display all the shipping details by using event handler? 
Thanks..

The given below is my xml code:

```
<global>
       <models>
           <User_Tracker>
               <class>User_Tracker_Model</class>
           </User_Tracker>
       </models>
       <events>
           <sales_order_place_after>
               <observers>
                   <User_Tracker>
                       <type>singleton</type>
                       <class>User_Tracker/observer</class>
                       <method>customOrderSave</method>
                   </User_Tracker>
               </observers>
           </sales_order_place_after>
       </events>
   </global>
```

and the given below is my observer code:

```
class User_Tracker_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 {
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('tracker/observer');
    }
    public function customOrderSave($observer)
     {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $customer_name = $order->getCustomerName();
      $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
      Mage::log($customer_id);
      Mage::log($customer_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all details from the order id.

```
public function customOrderSave($observer){
   $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();

   $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();          
   $customer_name = $order->getCustomerName();
   $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();

   $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId());

   $company= $shippingAddress->getCompany(); 
   $street = $shippingAddress->getStreet();
   $phone  = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
   $city   = $shippingAddress->getCity();
   $zip    = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
   $region = $shippingAddress->getRegion();

   foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {

    $product_id  = $item->getProductId();
    $orderedQty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $product_name  =$item->getName(); //to get the name
   }
}//END FUNCTION
```

Like this you can get all details related to ur order and Create your own log to see this value like below

```
Mage::log("Your Variables",true,'Yourownlog.log');
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: @Muajadh Can you help me more please. I want to access Product Name and Total Price as well. How can I get Product Name and Total Price?

Comment: upated the answer for getting the product name, Google for to get the order amount

Comment: @Muajadh and for total price? What should I do?  I used getPrice(), but it outputs for only 1 quantity, if I choose 3 quantities, it gives price of only a single quantity.

Comment: I mean I want to get the shipping amount.